# DXA 2.0 error":{"code":"9000","message":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Not possible to retrieve the dynamic configuration"}

Tags: dxa

After I ran the Sync-TtmCdEnvironment I am getting the below error in my .net application. Can someone help me on this issue?

[DataServiceClientException: {"error":{"code":"9000","message":"java.lang.RuntimeException: Not possible to retrieve the dynamic configuration"}}]

I have gone through the below article, however I do not see any record in CONFIGURATION_VALUE table.

I tested all the micro-services using postman. All the services are working fine.

https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000005260

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be Looks like discovery database broken.

Try to access this below URL in postman and confirm you are getting the result or not?

> http:/localhost:8085/client/v4/content.svc/GetPublicationMappingsFunctionImport(Url='http://localhost:8080/')

**Note:** Please change your registered BaseURL against your content service.

Expected result with your publication mapping id and baseURL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns:metadata="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/metadata" xmlns:data="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/data" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" metadata:context="http://localhost:8085/client/v4/content.svc/$metadata#PublicationMappings/$entity" xml:base="http://localhost:8085/client/v4/content.svc">
    <id>http://localhost:8085/client/v4/content.svc/PublicationMappings(NamespaceId=0,PublicationId=8)</id>
    <title></title>
    <summary></summary>
    <updated>2018-11-28T14:11:20.775Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name>SDL OData v4 framework</name>
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="PublicationMapping" href="PublicationMappings(NamespaceId=0,PublicationId=8)"></link>
    <category scheme="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/scheme" term="#Tridion.ContentDelivery.PublicationMapping"></category>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <metadata:properties>
            <data:NamespaceId metadata:type="Int32">0</data:NamespaceId>
            <data:PublicationId metadata:type="Int32">8</data:PublicationId>
            <data:Protocol>http</data:Protocol>
            <data:Domain>localhost</data:Domain>
            <data:Port>8852</data:Port>
            <data:Path>/</data:Path>
            <data:PathScanDepth metadata:type="Int32">100</data:PathScanDepth>
        </metadata:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

If there is no result, then I'm sure discovery database is broken for you.

Please raise it to SDL support.

or else, You could recreate your Discovery Service DB, register the Capabilities again and then use **Sync-TtmCdEnvironment** to synchronize with Topology Manager

**Note:**

if you add new BaseURL to existing setup  not required to run the **Sync-TtmCdEnvironment** it will auto sync, actually where it's really required to run this command if you Exporting and importing Content Delivery information between Topology instances in a DTAP setup, then it's required to run **Sync-TtmCdEnvironment**

I hope it helps.

Comment: Assuming you are using a separate DB for Discovery Service (rather than reusing the Content Data Store), any Discovery Service DB corruption can relatively easily be fixed: Create a new, empty Discovery Service DB, run the registration tool to re-register the Capabilities and use `Sync-TtmCdEnvironment ` to force sync Topology Manager with Discovery Service. (Oh, wait, that’s what you mentioned already :-)